# Can I use CircuitPython countio library on Raspberry pi 4B?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to read pulse with the 'countio' library from CircuitPython. When I'm importing the library, it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "fanfan.py", line 2, in 
> import countio
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'countio'

Here is the codes I used:

```
import board
import countio

# Count rising edges only.
pin_counter = countio.Counter(board.D1, edge=countio.Edge.RISE)
# Reset the count after 100 counts.
while True:
    if pin_counter.count >= 100:
        pin_counter.reset()
    print(pin_counter.count)
```

I tried

```
pip3 install countio
```

but it's not working.

Is there any way to install the countio library on Raspberry pi 4B?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it fails. Because it simply does NOT exist: [click me](https://pypi.org/search/?q=countio)

A very simpl look up on the homepage of **CircuitPython** revails the actual libraries:
[image]

So, to answer your question: No, there is no way to install countio library on any platform, because it does not exist.

Comment: I can find the documentations for countio here, but it doesn't seems to be available with pip3, https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/countio/index.html

Comment: What has the documentation to do with this?

Even so..., look up the documentation. It's very clear that **countio** is part of **CircuitPython**.